# How can I download Youtube videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, youtube

First i tried with youtube-dl and all the times ( and all days) for all videos it gives this same error:

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zWwTTAc7O8
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] 6zWwTTAc7O8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 6zWwTTAc7O8: Extracting video information
ERROR: format not available for video
```

Then I tried minitube latest version. but it just cant open the video. it just keeps trying to open video. it is unable to even play or download any video.

Also in old days, whenever i play video in youtube.com that was automatically was saved in my /tmp. But that is also not happening these days.

What can I use for downloading Youtube videos? I am using Lucid 64 bit.

Edit1: I dont want to use any extensions to Firefox. I like my firefox without any extension. With extension it becomes soooooo slow and inactive.

Comment: There are firefox/chrome extensions for saving Video and Audio from YouTube - is this an option?

Comment: the current version of [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/download.html) works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm), which will do this task with ease in 32 bit systems.

```
The producers haven't delivered yet a 64 bit version, but the 32 bit will download videos for youtube as in a native 32 bit system.
```

***Nowadays they have released a 64 bit version [right here](http://www.miksoft.net/products/mmc_1.7.7_amd64.deb).***

Additionally, take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27646/youtube-dl-error-please-help-in-this-to-resolve/27659#27659

Pasted here for your convenience:

> If you are interested on obtaining the
>   video take a look at this, other way
>   look into another answer in order to
>   see if you can solve your problem with
>   youtube-dl. Thank you.
>
> Notwithstanding that youtube-dl is
>   great in a terminal, there are several
>   ways to gather the videos from the
>   youtube buffer, one of which is the
>   usage of `totem` in order to play the
>   video and then extract the buffered
>   video from the `/tmp` folder.
>
> In the past (and depending on how
>   updated is your system: maybe your
>   case), the buffered videos were saved
>   into the `/tmp` folder also by some
>   browsers (Google Chrome and Chromium
>   Browser tested by me), but somehow
>   after updating that behaviour simply
>   stopped.
>
> When watching the videos  or simply by
>   open it to allow the buffer to
>   increase via web browser, now they are
>   saved into the
>   `/home/USERNAME/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache`
>   folder. (where USERNAME is your
>   username or home folder name).
>
> As I said before, the usage of totem
>   is yet observing this behaviour.

Comment: Ya, I was about to mention `/tmp` too, but that doesn't seem to be true anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your comment George Edison. /tmp buffering behaviour simply stopped working, so, after a couple of weeks trying to find a solution I found in google what I posted here. Even so, the Mobile Media Converter seems to continue working pretty fine. It is my favorite for now. :)

Comment: You guys know why that traditional /tmp way is not working ? it is the most easiest way for me to download youtube videos? But now it is not existing.

Comment: I knew about Mobile Media convertor before. But I did not knew that it also downloads youtube videos. So far as of now Mobile Media is the only GUI app worked for me to download youtube video. Command line is youtube-dl. Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't find the reference on which I readed that Google is implementing a new method for caching, which leads to prevent copyright issues, piracy and other facts. Unfortunatelly this seems not to be in our hands to re-program. Who knows? I haven't tried with the source code of chromium-browser but I think it can be achieved. Fortunatelly, this is Linux. There are lots of alternatives to almost everything.

Answer (score 5):

YouTube often changes their system, breaking such tools (probably deliberately) which means that the tools in the repositories quickly become out of date.

I recommend downloading the [latest version](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/download.html):

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/raw/2011.02.25c/youtube-dl
```

then running:

```
python youtube-dl URL
```

to download a video.

Comment: Getting the latest version of youtube-dl solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: It has a very litte issue though, that i need to cd to the directory where i have downloaded this latest youtube-dl so i can no save the video to custome location while downloading itself. Otherwise this command line way is perfect.

Comment: @Abhijit you can get around this issue by using the full path of the youtube-dl file. For example, if the youtube-dl file is in your Downloads folder and you want to download to your Videos folder you can cd to your Videos folder then run `python ~/Downloads/youtube-dl URL`

Answer (score 4):

1 - xviservicethief :

http://xviservicethief.sourceforge.net/

2 - Minitube :

http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube

3 - FatRat : available in the software center

4 - slimrat : available in the software center

5 - Jdownloader

Comment: It is surprising Minitube doesn't work for you, Abhijit Navale, but it still is a really good program to download videos. This advice would be appropriate for most of the people.

Comment: I know. I too loved minitube before when it was downloading videos properly. But now its not downloading. as you can see getting latest version of youtube-dl solved my issue that means youtube changed something in thier website and that change is not reflected in minitube. I have latest version of minitube. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Also I dont want fatrat because its qt and qt is so heavy it hangs my pc. and i tried slimrat, it has same problem as that of old youtube-dl and minitube - that its not updated with latest youtube changes.

Answer (score 3):

I use [clipgrab](http://clipgrab.de/en). I've only even been able to get it to work with Youtube, even though it claims to work with other sites. It has, however, never failed to download a Youtube video. Not sure how well it'll work on a 64 bit system.

Comment: But is clipgrab open source? as their site reads its free but is it open source too? (Yes I am quite aggressive about this. If i have qualty foss alternate for some task then i definitely will go for foss alternate!)

Comment: I downloaded clibgrab from above link you gave its .bz2 file. and it is giving error ./clipgrab-3.1.0.1: error while loading shared libraries: libphonon.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: It is open source, though it doesn't seem to mention it on the site. CNET downloads hosts it and specifies that it's open source, as do a few other sites (do a Google search for 'clipgrab' and you'll see). As for the error, I'm able to open it both from the command line and by double-clicking on it. There appear to be three packages in the software centre called `lipphonon-dev`, `libphonon4.4-cil` and `libphonon4`. I have the `libphonon4` installed, though I'm not sure what package brought it in. Do a search in the software centre for 'libphonon' and see if you have it installed.

Answer (score 3):

I use a launcher for running this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

FLASH_TMP=`ls /tmp | grep Flash*`

if [[ $FLASH_TMP ]]; then 
    vlc /tmp/Flash*
else
    if [[ `ps x | awk '/libgcflashplayer.so\ /{print $1}'` ]]; then
        flashvids() { lsof -p `ps x | awk '/libgcflashplayer.so\ /{print $1}'` -n 2>/dev/null | perl -lne '@F = split(/ +/, $_, 9); print "/proc/$F[1]/fd/${\($F[3] =~ /(^\d+)/)[0]}" if $F[4] eq "REG" && $F[8] =~ /\(deleted\)$/'; }
    else
        flashvids() { lsof -p `ps x | awk '/libflashplayer.so\ /{print $1}'` -n 2>/dev/null | perl -lne '@F = split(/ +/, $_, 9); print "/proc/$F[1]/fd/${\($F[3] =~ /(^\d+)/)[0]}" if $F[4] eq "REG" && $F[8] =~ /\(deleted\)$/'; }
    fi

    NOW=$(date +"%b-%d-%Y-%T")
    WHERE="/home/ashfame/Videos/youtube/$NOW.flv"
    echo $WHERE
    cp $(flashvids) $WHERE
    notify-send -i /home/ashfame/Dropbox/Ubuntu/icons/devil.png "Flash Video saved!" "It was named flash-video-$NOW.flv"
    vlc $(flashvids)
fi
```

Just change the locations as per your machine, make it executable and create a launcher pointing to it. Now whenever you run it, it will save the flash video (it will work for many sites other than youtube too) & open up the video in vlc. If you run it in between of the video being streamed, the video till that point will be saved and played in the player. So, if you just want to watch it, press as soon as you play & then pause the video or run it in the last.

It was originally only for viewing (found at http://www.webupd8.org/), but with some extra efforts, it saves them too.

Comment: this method doesn't depend on browser and is not for just youtube ;)

Comment: This is interesting. As this is not limited to youtube I will use it for other sites too. Thank you.

Comment: @Abhijit Please note that I have `vlc` and `libnotify` (for `notify-send`) installed.

Answer (score 2):

[FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/)

> FlashGot is the free add-on for Firefox and Thunderbird, meant to handle single and massive ("all" and "selection") downloads with several external Download Managers. FG contextual menu

Answer (score 1):

What if you use jdownloader? it will give the option of downloading every video you watch in youtube (as long as jdownloader is running when you do)

Answer (score 1):

"FlashGot" Addon for Firefox works great for me (10.04 64bit).

http://flashgot.net/

Click on a youtube video, then in the bottom right of the status bar is an icon that starts pulsing.  Click on it and it gives you options to download the video.  Works for much more than youtube.

Answer (score 1):

i shall give a easy way. when the video loading is complete in the firefox. just go to filesystem > tmp .you can see the flash video there. just copy it and save to any other place in hard disk.