# Where does the video we play on YouTube go?

Tags: video, folder, downloads

usually, the video I played  on YouTube completed I can find it on temp folder, but now nothing inside there after being played completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31077/how-can-i-download-youtube-videos/31084#31084), posted here for your convenience:

> You can use [Mobile Media
>   Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm), which will do this task
>   with ease in 32 bit systems. If you
>   are using a 64 bit version of Ubuntu
>   you may wish to follow [this
>   thread](http://israelremixteam.freeforums.org/how-to-install-32-bit-software-in-64-bit-system-t20.html) in order to make this
>   software install into a 64 bit system.
>   The producers haven't delivered yet a
>   64 bit version, but the 32 bit will
>   download videos for youtube as in a
>   native 32 bit system.

Additionally, take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27646/youtube-dl-error-please-help-in-this-to-resolve/27659#27659

Pasted here for your convenience:

> If you are interested on obtaining the
>   video take a look at this, other way
>   look into another answer in order to
>   see if you can solve your problem with
>   youtube-dl. Thank you.
>
> Notwithstanding that youtube-dl is
>   great in a terminal, there are several
>   ways to gather the videos from the
>   youtube buffer, one of which is the
>   usage of `totem` in order to play the
>   video and then extract the buffered
>   video from the `/tmp` folder.
>
> In the past (and depending on how
>   updated is your system: maybe your
>   case), the buffered videos were saved
>   into the `/tmp` folder also by some
>   browsers (Google Chrome and Chromium
>   Browser tested by me), but somehow
>   after updating that behaviour simply
>   stopped.
>
> When watching the videos  or simply by
>   open it to allow the buffer to
>   increase via web browser, now they are
>   saved into the
>   `/home/USERNAME/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache`
>   folder. (where USERNAME is your
>   username or home folder name).
>
> As I said before, the usage of totem
>   is yet observing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on flash version and the player used on the web site, the video is stored in the browser cache folder. However, depending on the space allocated for the cache, the video might be deleted after downloading. Additionally, if you are viewing a video that uses rtsp, then it won't be stored anywhere. is not the case for YouTube tho. The video should be in the browser cache folder.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser and on the version of flash player you use.
On Chrome with flash 10, it is usually under  `~/.cache/google-chrome/Cache`; similarly for Firefox, it is `~/.mozilla/firefox/<id>.default/Cache`.

Comment: ok thanks, but as I know basically after the video completely I played on youtube i will find it on temp folder. but since I updated my ubuntu, the video isn't there anymore. and I only can download it manually via DownThemAll

Answer (score 0):

Youtube videos are usually cached in `/tmp` for me. I'm using:

- Firefox 4 RC 2
- Chromium 11.0.662.0 (73963)
- Shockwave Flash 10.1.102
- Ubuntu 10.04 upgraded from 9.10 and 9.04 (at least).

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes for Flash 10.2 . Using this [script](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/play-youtube-videos-without-flash-from.html) from Webupd8 I can locate the files ( in /proc/ ) and play them in an external player.